# duvida com Entity Framework / SQL

Tags: entity-framework

tenho o seguinte script:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando a executo, obtenho a seguinte resposta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem quando executo pelo Entity Framework, o retorno é totalmente diferente, em todas as linhas, a resposta é a mesma, será algum bug? ou fiz algo errado?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o modelo:

```
public class PesquisaDashModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int qtde_resp { get; set; }
    public string pergunta { get; set; }
    public string resposta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde! <br/>
Qual o tipagem do seu atributo resposta?

Comment: é string, vou editar e colocar o modelo.

Comment: Você está conectado na base de dados correta?

Comment: estou sim, só tenho essa base

Comment: Ao invés de imagens cole seu código na pergunta assim como fez pro trecho em C#.

Comment: Você consegue por um breakpoint antes de serializar o objeto, para verificar se o bug é na serialização?

Comment: Bom dia @alessandremartins, conseguiu resolver?